# gmapping and inverted (upside-down) laser

Tags: ros, navigation, hokuyo-node, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello folks, I am having trouble using gmapping with my robot which has an upside-down laser. Last time I was building a map was probably in cturtle and it worked just fine. But in electric it seems that gmapping doesn't detect that the laser is inverted.

Looking at gmapping node source I can see that it uses "angle_increment" value of the LaserScan message to determine if the laser is inverted, e.g. if it is negative then the laser is upside-down. I did echo the messages coming from the laser and angle_increment is indeed positive, and the map is mirrored.

In hokuyo node source code angle_increment parameter is populated from the raw scan message coming from the laser driver, which wouldn't know anything about how the laser is mounted.

Am I missing something or did something change/break from previous release in either gmapping or hokuyo_node?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11952/gmapping-and-inverted-(upside-down)-laser/) by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2121 on 2011-11-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, there was definitely a bug in gmapping node, ticket with a patch is [here](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5250).

**Update:** I have uploaded our robot's [bag file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/48930510/wubble2_mapping.bag) that can be used to test proposed patches to gmapping, use this command to run gmapping: `rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=base_scan/scan _odom_frame:=odom_combined`. The laser in use is a Hokuyo URG-04LX mounted upside down on the front of the robot.

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2011-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0